# Get URL from active tab using python

Tags: python, html

Is there a way to get an html for **active** tab in browser (Firefox in my case) *without using selenium*?

Similar topics [were raised before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33841293/python-get-active-url-from-web-browser), but there were no clear answers.

Comment: get where? a python script in another process? would it be OK to write a browser extension in JS for this?

Comment: [It might be possible by reading Firefox profile's `sessionstore.js`](https://raymii.org/s/snippets/Get_the_current_or_all_Firefox_tab_urls_in_Bash.html)

Comment: By the way, what are you working on? Maybe you would be better of with Mechanize or PhantomJS instead of Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following code to get the source.For parsing use python library such as Beautiful Soup

```
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com")
page_source = response.read()
print page_source`
```